# Recursive directory to array in PHP; relative mapped to absolute

Tags: php, path, directory-structure

I'm pulling results from a recursive directory listing into an array, and was wondering if there is a better (*read faster, briefer, etc.*) way of doing it. Specifically, I'm creating an array of:

```
path_relative_to_somedir => absolute_path
```

Right now I've got:

```
$map = array();
$base_realpath = realpath('/path/to/dir');
$iterator = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($base_realpath);
foreach((new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator)) as $node){
    $node_realpath = $node->getRealpath();
    $map[substr($node_realpath, strlen($base_realpath) + 1)] = $node_realpath;
}
```

This works fine (*seemingly*) but I'm worried about edge cases that, while I'm sure they will come out in testing, others may be able to point out. So:

- Is there a better (*read faster, more accurate, more reliable*) way to get the node path relative to the `$base_realpath`?
- Should I consider options such as `glob()`, or `readdir()` as *faster* alternatives? (*this is a somewhat time sensitive operation, I saw a question pertaining to directory recursion in PHP with some benchmarks in an answer, will link when found*)

<sub>--Question ends--</sub>

---

<sub>--Possibly unnecessary detail begins--</sub>

**Purpose being**; I'm creating a *virtual working directory* for an application, so that calls to a given file are mapped to the actual file. For example: (*I'm elaborating in case someone has an overall better alternative approach based on what I'm actually doing*)

Given `dir1` is the "root" of the virtual working directory, and we wish to merge in `dir2`:

```
path/                       path/
|                           |
+-- to/                     +-- to/
    |                           |
    +-- dir1/                   +-- dir2/
        |                           |
        +-- script1.php             +-- script2.php
        |                           |
        +-- script2.php             +-- subdir/
        |                               | 
        +-- subdir/                     +-- script4.php
            |               
            +-- script3.php
```

It would yield an array like so:

```
[script1.php] => path/to/dir1/script1.php
[script2.php] => path/to/dir2/script2.php
[subdir/script3.php] => path/to/dir1/subdir/script3.php
[subdir/script4.php] => path/to/dir2/subdir/script4.php
```

Notice that the merging replaces existing relative paths, and each element is mapped to it's actual path. I'm simply using `array_replace()` here, here's the method snippet:

```
public function mergeModule($name){
    $path = realpath($this->_application->getPath() . 'modules/' . $name);
    if(!is_dir($path) || !is_readable($path)){
        // @todo; throw exception
    }
    $map = array();
    try{
        $directory_iterator = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
        foreach((new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory_iterator)) as $node){
            $node_realpath = $node->getRealpath();
            $map[substr($node_realpath, strlen($path) + 1)] = $node_realpath;
        }
    }catch(\Exception $exception){
        // @todo; handle
    }
    $this->_map = array_replace($this->_map, $map);
}
```

Comment: you're example has script2.php in the "to" directory and not the "dir2" directory which conflicts with your yielded output. Can you fix this?

Comment: Whoops, thanks @hafichuk - fixing.

Comment: This is barely worth mentioning, but keep in mind that PHP cannot easily be optimized, so it can be worth caching values like `strlen($base_realpath) + 1` outside the loop. I assume that `strlen` is a simple `O(1)` operation, but even function calls can add up if you make a lot of them.

Comment: @Matthew - True enough; I actually retyped the function in the SO edit box, I normally take such precautions. Actually, I'm wondering what's the best way to obtain the relative path of a given resource (*slice `path/to/dir` from `path/to/dir/subdir1/file2.php` - am I fine with using string length, or should I do something more intuitive?*)

Comment: @Bracketworks, the short of it is, I don't see anything particularly wrong with the way you are going about gathering the list of files. It's the same sort of technique I would use, including the `substr` to get the relative path. If you're concerned about speed, then try things out and do some benchmarks, but the underlying I/O should be the bottleneck regardless of which API you choose to use.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew - I figured my method was appropriate, however the `substr()` part is bothering me; PHP has no native functions to grab the suffix of a string, based on a supplied prefix; we're stuck with user-land implementations, let alone to perform any `get_path_relative_to()` operations. I'm a fan of `realpath()` both for path expansion and validation, however the fact that it returns paths using the separator associated with the OS is annoying, having to `strtr()` under many similar circumstances. Why PHP doesn't support a `use_unix_paths` INI directive, I'll never understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a faster way to list directories recursively you can try with external programs instead. A lot faster :)

```
exec('tree -if /var/www',$tree);
foreach($tree as $key => $path) {
    if ( !$path ) // Ignore the summary ex "5 directories, 30 files"
       break;

    // Do something with the file/dir path
}
```

If you only need .php files you can use the find command.

```
find . -name "*.php"
```

Comment: `tree` isn't available by default on most UNIX systems. `find` is (and you can omit the `-name "*.php"` to match all files), but it's unlikely to be particularly faster.